# app closing every time i log in with facebook

Tags: android, crash, facebook-login

Every time i log in with facebook in my app it get closed without any error...
But, this is the log i get when the app calls the loginfacebook dialog.

Help! and thanks.

> D/OpenGLRenderer: GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
>
> E/OpenGLRenderer:   GL_INVALID_VALUE
>
> E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 499K, 29% free 8575K/11996K, paused 23ms, total > 23ms
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
>
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
>
> D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 645K, 29% free 8565K/11996K, paused 17ms, total > 17ms
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> I/Choreographer: Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread
>
> E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
>
> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the > standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
>
> W/chromium: [WARNING:spdy_session.cc(2388)] Received WINDOW_UPDATE for invalid > stream 13
>
> W/chromium: [WARNING:spdy_session.cc(2388)] Received WINDOW_UPDATE for invalid > stream 15
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation
>
> D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 590K, 29% free 8605K/11996K, paused 54ms, total > 54ms
>
> E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
>
> E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
>
> E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This happens because your application is doing too much processing in UI thread
```

So do work with high processing on a different thread try implementing `Async Tasks`

check out below link
[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Comment: I changed that but im still getting the same issue without the log ...too much processing....

Comment: it was Manifest problem anyway i was doing too much processing in UI thread . i have I had android:noHistory="true" on my manifest file for the Activity. So whenever the facebook activity was being loaded the login activity was being destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I had android:noHistory="true" on my manifest file for the Activity. So whenever the facebook activity was being loaded the login activity was being destroyed.

changing to "false" solved it